# Dropdownlist not selecting the preselected value-mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am having strange issue, MVC dropdown selected value is not preselected on page Load.

My Models are:

```
public class DocumentTypesViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "DocumentType is required")]
        public int OHDocumentTypeId { get; set; }
        public string OHDocumentTypeDescription { get; set; }
    }



public class ClientAdvancedSearchViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "DocumentType")]
        public string DocumentTypeId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DocumentTypes { get; set; }
     }
```

In My Controllers I am populating the ClientAdvancedSearchViewModel like this

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ClientAdvancedSearch()
    {

        ClientAdvancedSearchViewModel clientAdvancedSearchViewModel = iClientReferralRecordsRepository.GetDocumentMetadata();
       //DocumentTypes Dropdown
        var ddlDocumentTypes = iDocumentTypeRepository.GetDocumentTypes();
        clientAdvancedSearchViewModel.DocumentTypes = new SelectList(ddlDocumentTypes, "OHDocumentTypeId", "OHDocumentTypeDescription",clientAdvancedSearchViewModel.DocumentTypeId);
        return View(clientAdvancedSearchViewModel);
    }
```

Finally in the View:

```
<td>
   <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DocumentTypes)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DocumentTypeId, Model.DocumentTypes, "Please Select", new { @id = "ddlDocumentType" })
     </div>
  </td>
```

I believe the Name of the dropdown is same is x => x.DocumentTypeId, becuase of this I think, my value is not preselected.

This is the ViewSource for generated HTML for the Drop Down

```
<select id="ddlDocumentType" name="DocumentTypeId">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="20">records</option>
<option value="21"> record1</option>
```

..

How can I rename my dropdownlist name or How can I solve my problem?

Thank you

Updated:  Added the missed line

```
ClientAdvancedSearchViewModel clientAdvancedSearchViewModel = iClientReferralRecordsRepository.GetDocumentMetadata();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code on your view is just right. You forgot to set the value for `DocumentTypeId`. This is your code as you posted:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ClientAdvancedSearch()
{
   //DocumentTypes Dropdown
    var ddlDocumentTypes = iDocumentTypeRepository.GetDocumentTypes();
    clientAdvancedSearchViewModel.DocumentTypes = new SelectList(ddlDocumentTypes, "OHDocumentTypeId", "OHDocumentTypeDescription",clientAdvancedSearchViewModel.DocumentTypeId);
    return View(clientAdvancedSearchViewModel);
}
```

And you missed this:

```
clientAdvancedSearchViewModel.DocumentTypeId = some_value;
```

Also, do you intend to have `DocumentTypeId` as an `int` instead of a `string`?

**UPDATE:**
You can also check that you set the id like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DocumentTypeId, new SelectList(Model.DocumentTypes, "Id", "Value", Model.DocumentTypeId), new { @id = "ddlDocumentType" })
```

Notice I used the overload with `new SelectList`. I don't remember all the overloads and I do it like that all the time, so you might check our the other overloads that suits your need.

Comment: I am setting it, but removed the line while pasting in SO. clientAdvancedSearchViewModel = iClientReferralRecordsRepository.GetDocumentMetadata();

Comment: Please post all relevant codes then for us to see. But see my updated answer too.